# Using C#, how do I set tab positions in a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, textbox, multiline

Is there a graceful way to set custom tab sizes/positions in a multiline textbox in C#?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? (note that I can't actually say whether this will make a difference!)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298406/how-to-set-the-tab-width-in-a-windows-forms-textbox-control

Comment: Based on his other questions, probably WinForms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to send the [EM_SETTABSTOPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761663%28VS.85%29.aspx) message, like this:

```
static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref int lParam);
}
static void SetTabs(TextBox box) {
    //EM_SETTABSTOPS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761663%28VS.85%29.aspx
    int lParam = 16;  //Set tab size to 4 spaces
    NativeMethods.SendMessage(box.Handle, 0x00CB, new IntPtr(1), ref lParam);
    box.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Man... you can find some nice tidbits site.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from by vb 2013 the friendly people at microsoft have decided you no longer need the windows handle and you can no longer get at it.