# C# Console Formatting

Tags: c#

I'm iterating through a list of objects of type Persons, and displaying the name and surname of each persons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("-|- Name: " + myList[i].GetName() +
                      "| Surname: " + myList[i].GetName() + "|");

}
```

The output in the console is as follows!

```
-|- Name: Abcdef | Surname: Asqw |
-|- Name: Aswer | Surname: Asdgfsdf |
-|- Name: Adxz | Surname: Asdsada |
```

I would like the output to be shown in the form of a table as below.

```
-|- Name: Abcdef | Surname: Asqw     |
-|- Name: Aswer  | Surname: Asdgfsdf |
-|- Name: Adxz   | Surname: Asdsada  |
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366124/inserting-a-tab-character-into-text-using-c-sharp

Comment: You would have to find the right amount of tab (`\t`) characters for a specified name length so that each one lines up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use composite formatting as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(
  "-|- Name: {0,-10} | Surname: {1,-10} |", 
  myList[i].GetName(),
  myList[i].GetName());
```

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = myList[i].GetName();
var surname = myList[i].GetName();
Console.WriteLine("-|- Name: {0,-10} | Surname: {1:-10} |", name, surname);
```

You can supply the padding parameter to the formatter. In this example, every column takes up at least 10 characters.

```
{0:-10}
  0   argument reference
  :   parameter separator
  -10 left-justified padding (exempting the `-` means it will pad to the right)
```

See the [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) docs for more information (since `Console.WriteLine(format, params args)` inherits this [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Use padRight to fill with spaces all the rows with less characters so you can align
all of them at same location:

```
Console.WriteLine( ("-|- Name: " + myList[i].GetName()).PadRight(20,' ') + 
                  ("| Surname: " + myList[i].GetName() ) + "|".PadRight(20,' ');
```

Comment: This does not pad each column but the whole string...

Comment: true. Let me update it ;)

Answer (score 1):

C#'s string has a PadRight method (`public string PadRight ( int totalWidth, char paddingChar );`). You can use this method to fill a string with a char as long as required to have it be it certain length. Drawback: you need to know what the longest text will by, so you night need to loop twice over the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `\t` in your strings everytime you would like to add a tabulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("-|- Name: {0,-10}| Surname: {1,-10}|", 
    myList[i].GetName(), 
    myList[i].GetSurname());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs (`\t`) in your strings, e.g:

```
 Console.WriteLine("-|- Name: " + myList[i].GetName() + "\t | Surname: "
                     + myList[i].GetName() + "\t |");
```

Add as many tabs as you need.

Or you can ensure each column takes up at least x characters:

```
Console.WriteLine("-|- Name: {0,-x}| Surname: {1,-x}|", 
    myList[i].GetName(), 
    myList[i].GetSurname());
```

Or you can use the `PadRight` method on each column (set x to the number you want):

```
Console.WriteLine( ("-|- Name: " + myList[i].GetName()).PadRight(x,' ') + 
                  ("| Surname: " + myList[i].GetName() ) + "|".PadRight(x,' ');
```