# Format text by adding whitespace

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to format strings by whitespaces.
All strings normally look like

```
01. Anton 30p
02. Cinderella 20p
03. Thomas 18p
04. Anastacia-Laura 16p
```

I want to format each string, that the points start at the same column.
There I wrote:

```
s = stringUpToName;
int addSpacing = 37 - s.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < addSpacing; i += 1) s += " ";

s += points;
```

It gets closer this way, but it's still not perfectly formatted.

I want it to look like this:

```
01. Anton            30p
02. Cinderella       20p
03. Thomas           18p
04. Anastacia-Laura  16p
```

Comment: This is not better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366124/inserting-a-tab-character-into-text-using-c-sharp

Comment: No :/ I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ["0" custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as zero-placeholder symbol to format index/number of record. `0:00` will give you `01` for value `1`.

Also keep in mind that [item format syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is *{ index[,alignment][:formatString]}* where alignment indicates preferred formatted field width. So, adding alignment to second item format `{1,20}` gives you right-aligned field width of 20 characters. With negative alignment field will be left-aligned.

Total format string will look like `"{0:00}. {1,-20}{2}p"`

You can use it with `String.Format` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` if you are build string, or `Console.WriteLine` if you are writing it to console.

```
int index = 1;
string name = "Anton";
int points = 30;
var result = String.Format("{0:00}. {1,-20}{2}p", index, name, points)
// "01. Anton               30p"
```

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: I just tested this: Wrong output.

Comment: @Saphire sorry, you need negative alignment for left-align field. Updated

Answer (score 0):

String.Format and [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using the Alignment functionality

```
string[] names = new string[]
{
    "1. Anton 30p",
    "2. Cinderella 20p",
    "3. Thomas 18p",
    "4. Anastacia-Laura 16p"
};

foreach(string s in names)
{
    int lastSpace = s.LastIndexOf(' ');
    int firstSpace = s.IndexOf(' ');
    string result = string.Format("{0,-4}{1,-37}{2,4}", s.Substring(0, firstSpace), s.Substring(firstSpace + 1, lastSpace), s.Substring(lastSpace+1));
    Console.WriteLine(result);

}
```

Keep in mind that to see the output exactly aligned in columns you need to use a Fixed Width font like Lucida Console or Courier, because fonts with variable width use less pixel to print an I than to print a W.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-align the numbers using

String.Format("{0} {1} {2,4}p",
Num,
Name,
Point);